# Tight upper and lower bounds of the CDF of a summation of random variables

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, upper-lower-bounds

I have this random variable

$$Y = \sum_{k=1}^KX_k$$

where $X_k$ are i.i.d. random variables with CDF and PDF $F_X(x)$ and $f_X(x)$, respectively.

In my application, the CDF of $Y$ denoted by $F_Y(y)=\text{Pr}\left[Y\leq y\right] = \text{Pr}\left[\sum_{k=1}^KX_k\leq y\right]$ is not easy to evaluate directly. So, I am trying to find a tight lower and upper bound, such that the exact CDF is very close to both.

One obvious options for the lower and upper bounds are

$$\text{Pr}\left[K\min_k X_k\leq y\right]\geq \text{Pr}\left[\sum_{k=1}^KX_k\leq y\right] \geq \text{Pr}\left[K\max_k X_k\leq y\right]$$

I have done some simulations on the lower bound, and it is lose. What are other lower and upper bounds that I can use?

EDIT: In my application, $X_k=A_k/B_k$, where $A_k$ and $B_k$ are i.i.d exponential random variables with parameter 1, and the means of such random variables don't exist.

Comment: Here’s a [potentially useful paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7792589/) (paywall)

Comment: @DavidM. Thanks, but this method depends on the mean of the summation. In my case, the means don't exist. In my application $X_k=A_k/B_k$, where both $A_k$ and $B_k$ are exponential RVs with parameter 1.

Comment: Ahhh gotcha I think it would be helpful if you edit your post and add that info

Comment: @DavidM. Just did. Do you have another suggestion in light of the new information?

Comment: Not off the top of my head—will post if I think of anything

Comment: I guess you couldn't get something reasonable for $X_i$'s with unbounded first moment. I initially was thinking about concentration bounds for the sum of random variables, but they are inapplicable due to the reason mentioned above. So, expecting something tight sounds very optimistic to me. 

You can easily compute the CDF and PDF of $X_i$ though, but convolutions are really heavy when $K > 3$.